# CentOS 7 and MariaDB issue

Tags: mariadb, centos7

I have recently moved to DigitalOcean, and installed Centos7 along with its default MysQl server (MariaDB).

But I am facing since first install.
MySql is exiting down spontaneously and there is no memory issue. I checked using:

```
egrep -i "out of memory|oom" /var/log/dmesg
egrep -i "cannot allocate memory|can't allocate" /var/log/mysql*/error.log
```

I am worried that why mysql is not restarting itself after closing ?

is this a MariaDB bug ? how can I fix it ?
Anyway to check why its closing ?

Currently I am using `crontab -e` for restarting MySql, but that did not helped a lot.

Thanks for the help

found some logs in mariadb.log:

```
150105  7:20:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
150105  7:20:03 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
150105  7:20:03 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150105  7:20:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.40-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
150105  7:21:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

150105  7:21:25 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150105  7:21:25  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150105  7:21:26  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1619889
150105  7:21:26 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150105 07:21:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: Does your digital ocean instance have swap space enabled? How much RAM is in the instance? based on the log file you've posted, its unclear why it is exiting -- in fact its stating a normal shutdown at 7:21:25 -- what happened between 7:30:03 -> 7:21:25 ?

Answer (score 0):

... assuming you have enough RAM to run `mysqld`, try running [MySQLTuner-perl by major](http://mysqltuner.com/) and tweak your `my.ini`.